# What is the best way to monitor Heroku Postgres memory and cpu

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

We're on Heroku and trying to understand if it's time to upgrade our Postgres database or not. I have two questions:

1. Is there any tools you know of that track heroku postgres logs to track their memory and cpu 
   usage stats over time?
2. Are those (Memory and CPU usage) even the best metrics to look at to determine if we should upgrade to a larger instance or not?

Answer (score 1):

The most useful tool I've found for monitoring heroku postgres instancs is the logs associated with the database's dyno, which you can monitor using `heroku logs -t -d heroku-postgres`. This spits out some useful stats every 5 minutes, so if you fill your logs up quickly, this might not output anything right away — use `-t` to wait for the next log line.

Output will look something like this:

```
2022-06-27T16:34:49.000000+00:00 app[heroku-postgres]: source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_SILVER addon=postgresql-fluffy-55941 sample#current_transaction=81770844 sample#db_size=44008084127bytes sample#tables=1988 sample#active-connections=27 sample#waiting-connections=0 sample#index-cache-hit-rate=0.99818 sample#table-cache-hit-rate=0.9647 sample#load-avg-1m=0.03 sample#load-avg-5m=0.205 sample#load-avg-15m=0.21 sample#read-iops=14.328 sample#write-iops=15.336 sample#tmp-disk-used=543633408 sample#tmp-disk-available=72435159040 sample#memory-total=16085852kB sample#memory-free=236104kB sample#memory-cached=15075900kB sample#memory-postgres=223120kB sample#wal-percentage-used=0.0692420374380985
```

The main stats I pay attention to are `table-cache-hit-rate` which is a good proxy for how much of your active dataset fits in memory, and `load-avg-1m`, which tells you how much load per CPU the server is experiencing.

You can read more about all these metrics [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-metrics-logs).

Comment: Is there an easy way to ingest and visualize those metrics graphically over time?

Comment: Trying librato as recommended here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-database-tuning#track-metrics